# How to WhenAll when some tasks can be null?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I would like to wait all task, but some of them can be null. It is a code like that:

```
Task<MyType1> myTask1 = getData01Async();
Task<MyTyp2> myTask2 = null;
Task<MyType3> myTask3 = null;

if(myVariable == true)
{
    myTask2 = getData02Async();
}
else
{
    myTask3 = getData03Async();
}


wait Task.WhenAll(myTask1, myTask2, myTask3);
```

The idea is, task1 always exists, but task2 and task3 depends of a variable. So I would like to run all the task in parallel and wait when all of them are finished. And if one task is null, the treat it as it is finished.

The problem with this code is that I get a null reference exception when it runs.

There are some way to do that? Or what another alternatives could I use?

Comment: How about putting the tasks into an explicit collection and using `myTasks.Where(t => t!=null)` to pass to `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: myTask1 ?? Task.CompletedTask

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd `Task.CompletedTask` can't return result

Comment: @Fabjan meh, since they're all different `T` in the `Task<T>` sense, that won't matter - it is the `params Task[]` overload, and `Task.CompletedTask` is definitely a `Task`

Comment: @MarcGravell I only meant that it's not really possible to do this assignment: `Task<MyType1> myTask1 = Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: @UweKeim That's exactly what I was thinking, could make a good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a collection to track the tasks that aren't `null`. Then pass that list to `Task.WhenAll` method like below:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

Task<MyType1> myTask1 = getData01Async();
tasks.Add(myTask1);

Task<MyTyp2> myTask2 = null;
Task<MyType3> myTask3 = null;

if(myVariable == true)
{
    myTask2 = getData02Async();
    tasks.Add(myTask2);
}
else
{
    myTask3 = getData03Async();
    tasks.Add(myTask3);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 17):

Just filter the null tasks out:

```
await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { task1, task2, task3 }.Where(i => i != null));
```

Comment: Was this meant to be different than the answer I gave?

Comment: @JSteward I didn't look at your answer (the purpose of mine was to make it short so I didn't dig the long ones), but yes - it's the same.

Comment: Fair enough, just had to ask

Answer (score 11):

Well, depending on your scenario you *could* assign completed tasks or put them in an array/list and then pass this list to `WhenAll`:

```
Task<MyType1> myTask1 = getData01Async();
Task<MyType2> myTask2 = Task.FromResult((MyType2) null);
Task<MyType3> myTask3 = Task.FromResult((MyType3) null);

...

await Task.WhenAll(myTask1, myTask2, myTask3);
```

Comment: Thanks, This really helped me out.
I had multiple tasks with different result types of which I was not sure the tasks should trigger.
And with this solution I could still work with the results without worrying about what type the generic Task returned when adding everything to a list!

Comment: The only non-obvious suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best solution. Very easy to just do myTask = x != null ? MyAsync() : Task.CompletedResult instead of creating arrays and filtering on them.

Answer (score 3):

To build on what @UweKeim suggested, why not simply filter out the null tasks when you pass them to the `WhenAll`.

```
public async Task FilterNullTasks()
{
    Task<string> myTask1 = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(tsk => string.Empty);
    Task<int> myTask2 = null;
    Task<bool> myTask3 = null;

    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]
    {
        myTask1, myTask2, myTask3
    }.Where(tsk => tsk != null));
}
```